# Jmeter use variable to create variable and retrieve value

Tags: variables, get, jmeter

I know the title may be confusing but this is what I need to do:

I have a list of variables I am pulling from Jquery extractor.

```
 myVar_1 = 343
 myVar_2 = 98763
 myVar_3 = 5622 
etc
```

I generate a random number between `1` and `myVar_matchNr`.

Then I want to navigate to a URL that has an ID of one of the randomly selected variables.  For instance, this would be the path I would like as an example:

```
//mydomain.com/api/resource/${myVar_${randomNumber}}
```

Which would translate to ( in the case my random number was 2):

```
 //mydomain.com/api/resource/98763
```

I have the random number, and I have the list of variables from the `Jquery` extractor, but I have been unsuccessful getting the value out of the combination.

I have tried the above URL directly.
I have tried a beanshell script that looked something like:

```
 String myvarString = "myVar_" + get("myRandNumber");
 String myVar = get(myvarString);
 set("mySelectedVar", myVar);
```

That seemed to always come up an empty string.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine 2 variables using [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) like

```
${__V(myVar_${randomNumber})}
```

In regards to Beanshell, you need to use `vars` object which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance to manipulate the JMeter Variables like

```
String myvarString = "myVar_" + vars.get("myRandNumber");
String myVar = vars.get(myvarString);
vars.put("mySelectedVar", myVar);
```

See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article for more information on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

One more option is Random Controller, you can create 3 different request and place it under Random Controller.i hope this will serve the purpose.